# Ormlite change order of query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have create a query in orm lite like this :

```
TAbleA.queryBuilder()
                        .where()
                        .eq("col1", Wait)
                        .or()
                        .eq("col2", Fail)
                        .and()
                        .isNull("col3")
                        .or()
                        .le("col4", fromThisTime)
                        .prepare();
```

it prepare this query :

```
MappedStatement: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TableA` WHERE (((`col1` = 'Wait' OR `col2` = 'Fail' ) AND `col3` IS NULL ) OR `col4` <= '2018-11-18 13:08:03.637000' )
```

but I want to change it to :

```
MappedStatement: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TableA` WHERE (`col1` = 'Wait' OR `col2` = 'Fail' ) AND (`col3` IS NULL OR `col4` <= '2018-11-18 13:08:03.637000' )
```

how can I do it ?!

**I want to change `AND` and `OR` order.**

can Someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#QueryBuilder-Basics) the easiest way is :

```
TAbleA.queryBuilder()
                    .where()
                    .eq("col1", Wait)
                    .eq("col2", Fail)
                    .or(2)
                    .isNull("col3")
                    .le("col4", fromThisTime)
                    .or(2)
                    .and(2)
                    .prepare();
```

otherwise you can write your complex query using **post-order**